# Get the IP address of the client connecting to a C# .NET WebAPI application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, ip, asp.net-web-api2

I tried:

```
private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";

public static string GetClientIpAddress(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext))
    {
        dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
    }

    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage))
    {
        dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
        if (remoteEndpoint != null)
        {
            return remoteEndpoint.Address;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

according to:

[Retrieving the client's IP address in ASP.Net Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/05/retrieving-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-web-api/)

this is the combined approach which should be valid for self host and webapi host. Unfortunately I get `null` instead of the IP address.

I'm trying locally so I'd expect `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as the IP address

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of what you have that works for me.

```
static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions {

    private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
    private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";
    private const string OwinContext = "MS_OwinContext";

    public static string GetClientIpString(this HttpRequestMessage request) {
        //Web-hosting
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext)) {
            dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
            if (ctx != null) {
                return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }
        }
        //Self-hosting
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage)) {
            dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
            if (remoteEndpoint != null) {
                return remoteEndpoint.Address;
            }
        }
        //Owin-hosting
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(OwinContext)) {
            dynamic ctx = request.Properties[OwinContext];
            if (ctx != null) {
                return ctx.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
            }
        }
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null) {
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        // Always return all zeroes for any failure
        return "0.0.0.0";
    }

    public static IPAddress GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request) {
        var ipString = request.GetClientIpString();
        IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(0);
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(ipString, out ipAddress)) {
            return ipAddress;
        }

        return ipAddress;
    }

}
```

Assuming you are in a controller the above extension method allows for calls like:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;

var ip = request.GetClientIpString();
```

Comment: what the "this" is all about? I mean, on the after the parameter

Comment: its an extension method. When in a static class is allows for calls like `request.GetClientIpString();`

Comment: I get ::1 from my localhost webapi.. do you think is it correct? Is it an alias for 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: That is correct ::1 is ipv6 for localhost which is the same as ipv4 version of 127.0.0.1