# Get IP address of requested client in WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have tried the same using code below. Since I tested my code from my local machine with Postman, the result remains `::1` and post deployment this become `null`.

```
private string GetIPAddress()
 {
   HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
   string ipAddress = context?.Request?.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
                if (addresses.Length != 0)
                    return addresses[0];
            }

            return context?.Request?.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095938/get-the-ip-address-of-the-client-connecting-to-a-c-sharp-net-webapi-application)

Comment: @Lloyd Thanks. This works as expected.